# como puedo filtrar un print en python con pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

estoy viendo tutoriales pero no encuentro lo que necesito , [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hay alguna forma de imprimir solamente los que calificaron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes filtrar por columna llamando en paréntesis el nombre de la columna y el valor deseado:

```
print(data[data['califico']=='Si'])
```